# editing in place for a has one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I use any of the edit in place gems par example: best_in_place, to edit the properties of the child model in a has_one  and or has_many relationships.

Example:  (Just an example, not the actual Issue; used for explanation.)
 A user model has many goals (goal model) and for each goal there are some properties. How do i use the gem 'best_in_place' to edit these properties from the show page.

Tried it as show in "In-Place Editing" on Railscast, http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing, but ended up with errors such as `"undefined method :property for goal"` Also tried `@user.goal` in the spot for model class to no avail.

Actually Code can be seen below.

I'm actually using it to edit a user's profile attributes but similar concepts and errors..

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecored::Base
   has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
   after_create :build_profile

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes

   def build_profile
     Profile.create(user_id: self.id)
   end
end
```

Profile.rb

```
 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name. :address, :age
   belongs_to :user

   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
   validates :address, :age,  presence: true
 end
```

Users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @profile = self.build_profile 
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save 
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "welcome, Thanks for Signing up"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
 end

end
```

Profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

 def edit 
   @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
   @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
   if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
     flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'edit'
   end
 end

 def show 
   @user.profile = User.find(params[:id]).profile
 end

 def destroy
 end
end
```

User/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Profile" ) %>
<h1><%= @user.profile.name %></h1>

<p>
  <b> Address  </b> <%= best_in_place @profile, :address, :path => user_profile_path(@user, @profile) %>
</p>
```

Database Tables (with User_id as the foreign key )

```
USER TABLE                                                PROFILE TABLE
 ------------------------                                 ------------------------
|   Id                   | ----------                    |        Id              |
 ------------------------            |                    ------------------------
|  Email                 |           ------------------  |     User_id            |
 ------------------------                                 ------------------------
| Password               |                               |     Name               |
 ------------------------                                 ------------------------
| Password Confirmation  |                               |      Address           |
 ------------------------                                 ------------------------
| Remember Token         |                               |       Age              |
 ------------------------                                 ------------------------
| Created At             |                               | Created At             |
 ------------------------                                 -------------------------                                  
| Updated At             |                               | Updated At             |
 ------------------------                                 -------------------------
```

Comment: did you remember to run `rake db:migrate`? Otherwise, describe your model and database structure a bit

Comment: @derekyau yes, the database was updated and contained the necessary columns.

Comment: can you post some model code?

Comment: @derekyau, Added some code though I am yet to allow the model respond json.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `update` action to your `profiles_controller`

something like this:

```
def update
  @profile = Profile.find params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@profile) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, i had noticed the update function was missing which i had added after pasting my code, but still no avail. I was still getting the error of undefined method..

Comment: one thing I don't understand is why are you getting undefined method `goal` when you are trying to edit the 'profile.address` in the code that you've pasted? - is there more that isn't here?

Comment: Oh that was only an example i used to explain the kind of error i was getting, will edit my post so no one gets confused and also add the update action i added to the controller...

Comment: can you also make sure you ran `rake db:migrate` and perhaps detail how your database schema is?